# "Segmentation fault" error when using Gstreamer on Raspbian

Tags: python

I installed Gsreamer on Raspbian with `apt-get install gstreamer1.0`
. when I want run my Gstreamer application(writen with pyqt4) On Raspbian, I get "Segmentation fault" error. I should say when I run my Gstreamer application on Ubuntu It run without anny error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there is a bug in the `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad`. 
this [link](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=740191#bug_status_bottom) is the bug report and this [link](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/commit/?id=3e1d7630187dd96b137553aec2c6edb60c213682) is the patch for it.
I applied the patch to it and compile it by myself and there was no error anymore.